# How to edit azure service principal manifest from command line

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to change azure service principal groupMembershipClaims property from command line. I check already

- [Graph API beta](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/serviceprincipal_update)
- [PowerShell Set-AzureRmADApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/set-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-5.0.0)
- [PowerShell Set-AzureRmADServicePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/set-azurermadserviceprincipal?view=azurermps-5.0.0

Am I blind or what? Is there any way to do this without Azure portal and manual clicking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Azure AD v2 cmdlets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0

```
Set-AzureAdApplication -ObjectId xxx -GroupMembershipClaims 'All'
```

Answer (score 0):

using azure cli as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-update) : 
`az ad app update --id <appId> --set groupMembershipClaims=All`